# Library to read a QR Code in a Salesforce community from a web browser on mobile phone

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, mobile, phone, qr-code

I develop a LWC which scans a QR code from a Salesforce a community by using a web browser on a mobile phone.

I searched on the internet and the Salesforce library BarcodeScanner doesn't work because we use a web browser and the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_compatibility) explains that:

> It does not and cannot function when running in a web browser, whether
> the browser runs on a desktop or mobile device.

I tried with [HTML5 QR Code Scanner](https://blog.minhazav.dev/research/html5-qrcode) but it doesn't work because is uses element id and it is not support in LWC.

I tried with an iframe from LWC which calls a Visualforce page and the above library because I get an error message because the request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.

Do you know a library compatible with my context please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the Salesforce library doesn't work from a web browser on a mobile phone? A quick check might be to run say this app: https://gitlab.com/johnjvester/lwc-calorie-counter.

Comment: Yes I am sure (first part in bold): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_compatibility

"It does not and cannot function when running in a web browser, whether the browser runs on a desktop or mobile device."

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use `lwc:dom="manual"` (see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives) and embed the required HTML in your LWC with the required ID?

Comment: Did you manage to reach an optimal solution ? please provide an answer as i am stuck in the same issue.